# Magento 2 : Custom minicart

Tags: magento2, custom, mini-cart, magento2.3.2

I have a custom free shipping bar in minicart, and how can I move it to before "View And Edit Cart", hope anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: is your bar a html template?

Comment: https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/blog/how-to-add-free-shipping-bar-in-top-mini-cart/ Thank for your reply, please check it.